# Rails4: Bug might be caused by adding new obj in index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

***Model relationship:***
material has many expresses
express belongs to material

expressesController.rb

```
def index
    @express = @material.expresses.new
    @expresses = @material.expresses
end
```

***Problem:***
There is always a null row in the table of @expresses even though it is an empty. Even when @express is not empty, a null row always in the bottom of the table.

I am not sure but I think the problem happens because I put `@express = @material.expresses.new` in the index action.

Could anyone tell me what causes the problem and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: you maybe submitted an empty form once in earlier stage, check the database from `console`

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun I checked from database, no record there

Comment: Try `@material.expresses.build` instead of `new`

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun Hi, it does not work. After debug the code, I am sure the  material.expresses.new cause the problem.  It is weird, database has no record, but when I try to use <% if  expresses == [ ] %> , it returns false...

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun When I try  puts expresses.all ,the log returns like this: CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "expresses".* FROM "expresses" WHERE "expresses"."material_id" = ?  [["material_id", 2]]

Comment: then try `Express.all.destroy` in the `console`

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun Not work either, maybe the new causes cache, if I remove material.expresses.new everything ok, however I need it ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125047/discussion-between-moataz-zaitoun-and-marco-song).

Comment: Please provide your view code where you are showing the expresses

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two ways first replace your controller code with

```
 def index
   @expresses = @material.expresses
   @express = @material.expresses.new
 end
```

or add a check in your view where you listing @expresses like

```
@expresses.each do |express|
  unless express.new_record?
    # your view code
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, finally it works after I try expresses = material.expresses.all 
Do you know why it works?